# unable to type properly in redis-cli

Tags: redis

There is a problem to type properly in redis-cli.

At first redis-cli run, a line "127.0.0.1:6379 > " is printed in terminal.
It seems normal.
But the problem is this.. Whenever I type any key, "127.0.0.1:6379 > " repeatedly printed in terminal.

For example,
I typed "keys *" in redis-cli, 
and then "127.0.0.1:6379> 127.0.0.1:6379> k127.0.0.1:6379> ke127.0.0.1:6379> key127.0.0.1:6379> keys127.0.0.1:6379> keys*" is printed in redis-cli.

It's really disturbing me. 
Could anyone help me to fix this problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a terminal issue. 
What terminal do you use? 
What does the following print:

```
  echo $TERM
```

Can you run successfully with the following?

```
  TERM=dumb redis-cli
```